# Линия(полоска) в css

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать выделенную линию(полоску) в css под текстом с отступами?

Comment: p:after - пробовали ?

Comment: А какие стили применить к псевдоэлементу  after?

Comment: width: 20px; height: 2px; background: #ccc; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left; 0; content: "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 22%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок<h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не использовать тег hr для этого? Или решение должно быть чисто на css?

Comment: А как у hr добавить отступ?

Comment: через стили, в принципе